# Make monadic functions invocation point free

Tags: haskell

I have code that compiles:

```
\f st -> f1 >>= \m-> f2 m f st
```

f1 is of type `m a` and f2 of type `a -> b -> c -> m d`, in the same Monad m. I can't for the life of me rewrite this expression pointfree, without the ugly \f st and the \m in the middle. I would like to, not for aesthetics but because I have other equations for the same function that I can write pointfree, so it would make the code a lot easier to understand.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Well, `pointfree` returns `((f1 >>=) .) . flip . flip f2`. Is that really easier for you to understand?

Comment: If it's this hard to make it point-free, it's probably not a good idea to make it point-free. ;-)

Comment: Thanks Zeta, I should have run pointfree first, of course. The version with flip is not easier, but f2 is mine to change, so I can change it to `b -> c -> a -> md`and the expression becomes `(((f1 >>=) .) .) f2`

Answer (score 2):

Well, here's my joke answer:

- λ f st → f1 >>= λ m → f2 m f st
- [λ f st → f1 >>= [λ m → f2 m f st]]
- [λ f st → f1 >>= S [λ m → f2 m f] [λ m → st]]
- [λ f st → f1 >>= S [λ m → f2 m f] (K st)]
- [λ f st → f1 >>= S (S [λ m → f2 m] [λ m → f]) (K st)]
- [λ f st → f1 >>= S (S [λ m → f2 m] (K f)) (K st)]
- [λ f st → f1 >>= S (S [f2] (K f)) (K st)]
- [λ f st → f1 >>= S (S f2 (K f)) (K st)]
- [λ f st → (>>=) f1 (S (S f2 (K f)) (K st))]
- [λ f → [λ st → (>>=) f1 (S (S f2 (K f)) (K st))]]
- [λ f → S [λ st → (>>=) f1] [λ st → S (S f2 (K f)) (K st)]]
- [λ f → S (K ((>>=) f1)) [λ st → S (S f2 (K f)) (K st)]]
- [λ f → S (K ((>>=) f1)) (S [λ st → S (S f2 (K f))] [λ st → K st])]
- [λ f → S (K ((>>=) f1)) (S [λ st → S (S f2 (K f))] [K])]
- [λ f → S (K ((>>=) f1)) (S [λ st → S (S f2 (K f))] K)]
- [λ f → S (K ((>>=) f1)) (S (K (S (S f2 (K f)))) K)]
- S [λ f → S (K ((>>=) f1))] [λ f → S (K (S (S f2 (K f)))) K]
- S (K (S (K ((>>=) f1)))) [λ f → S (K (S (S f2 (K f)))) K]
- S (K (S (K ((>>=) f1)))) (S [λ f → S (K (S (S f2 (K f))))] [λ f → K])
- S (K (S (K ((>>=) f1)))) (S [λ f → S (K (S (S f2 (K f))))] (K K))
- S (K (S (K ((>>=) f1)))) (S (S [λ f → S] [λ f → K (S (S f2 (K f)))]) (K K))
- S (K (S (K ((>>=) f1)))) (S (S (K S) [λ f → K (S (S f2 (K f)))]) (K K))
- S (K (S (K ((>>=) f1)))) (S (S (K S) (S [λ f → K] [λ f → S (S f2 (K f))])) (K K))
- S (K (S (K ((>>=) f1)))) (S (S (K S) (S (K K) [λ f → S (S f2 (K f))])) (K K))
- S (K (S (K ((>>=) f1)))) (S (S (K S) (S (K K) (S [λ f → S] [λ f → S f2 (K f)]))) (K K))
- S (K (S (K ((>>=) f1)))) (S (S (K S) (S (K K) (S (K S) [λ f → S f2 (K f)]))) (K K))
- S (K (S (K ((>>=) f1)))) (S (S (K S) (S (K K) (S (K S) (S [λ f → S f2] [λ f → K f])))) (K K))
- S (K (S (K ((>>=) f1)))) (S (S (K S) (S (K K) (S (K S) (S (K (S f2)) [λ f → K f])))) (K K))
- S (K (S (K ((>>=) f1)))) (S (S (K S) (S (K K) (S (K S) (S (K (S f2)) [K])))) (K K))
- S (K (S (K ((>>=) f1)))) (S (S (K S) (S (K K) (S (K S) (S (K (S f2)) K)))) (K K))

The functions S and K are defined by

```
k :: x -> y -> x
k x y = x

s :: (x -> y -> z) -> (x -> y) -> (x -> z)
s f g x = (f x) (g x)
```

Anybody who tries to actually use this is of course crazy. ;-)

Comment: It's hard to counter that this does not answer the question, since it does exactly what was asked. Well played, sir, well played...

Comment: I'm glad somebody has a sense of humor. :-)